# Remote mysql database on Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Can I use mysql database from my personal web server instead of heroku's database?

I configured my production database like this:

```
production:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: somedatabase
    username: someusername
    password: somepassword
    host: 1.1.1.1:1234
```

But, this doesn't work, my app still uses heroku's shared database.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is old but in case anyone drops around looking for an answer, it's much easier than using the gem. Just provide a `DATABASE_URL` and `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` (not sure if the second is needed). The database url format is `adapter://username:password@hostname:port/database`, so for example, you would do:

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://etok:somepassword@<your-server>:3306/etok
heroku config:add SHARED_DATABASE_URL=mysql://etok:somepassword@79.101.41.213:3306/etok
```

Then re-deploy your app. It will read your `DATABASE_URL` and generate the database.yml from that. The default port is already 3306 so it's not needed in the url in your case. When you deploy, you may notice that it generates your database.yml:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
```

Then you're set (as long as your server accepts connections from your heroku host.

Comment: It seems `DATABASE_URL` is enough, it works without specifying `SHARED_DATABASE_URL`. Also, I'd like to notice that `mysql2` adapter is now more common than `mysql`. So it will be looks like `mysql2://...`. Of course you have to add `gem 'mysql2'` in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Can X.509 be used this way?

Comment: "In case `anyone` drops around looking for an answer". You've just saved my day. Thank you! This is much simpler than I could have thought.

Comment: "as long as your server accepts connections from your heroku host.",  I'm deploying a PHP application and heroku's host is constantly changing.  I keep getting `Host 'ec2-xxxxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`, where xxxx is some arbitrary IP.  I can't just allow one specific IP because it is changing on the fly.  Do you have any advice for this?

Comment: @augie-gardner unfortunately not - i guess your best shot (or the narrowest filter) would be to add a wildcard account name in your mysql server to match all ec2-%.compute-1.amazonaws.com (and work up from there). Personally I'd just go for %.amazonaws.com and set a lengthy secure password. If you're attacked from aws servers, at least you know who to email.

Answer (score 8):

I've written a gem that may help with this.  You can find it at:

http://github.com/nbudin/heroku_external_db

Comment: Thanks Nat. I've been used using your gem for one month and it works just fine!

Comment: We also have been using this for about a year.  I added some documentation to that project so it's easier to get started.  Here's a link to the writeup on my blog:  http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2011/11/21/using-heroku-with-an-external-mysql-database/

Answer (score 5):

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@databasehostIP:3306/databasename
heroku config:add SHARED_DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@databasehostIP:3306/databasename
```

Then, do a

```
Heroku restart
```

that should do.

Important Note: I suggest you to use database host IP address than using giving the hostname directly, coz, with some shared hosting services like godaddy, the db hostname looks like ***user.345432.abcd.godaddy.com*** and it seems like heroku is unable to resolve it properly (personal experience), I resolved the hostname to IP address and using the IP directly worked like a charm ! Also, If your database password has special characters, make sure you escape them correctly (like '\!' for '!' and so on..)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [Heroku Amazon RDS addon](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon_rds). I'm not saying use it, but it gives you an insight into what you need to do and how Heroku manages dataabases - basically you need to set a config variable to your mysql instance.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku ignores your database.yml. You will need to explore the Amazon RDS solution John Beynon suggested or some other similar addon (if there is one). IMO, you will either have to re-evaluate your need to use your MySQL db or find some other hosting.
Just in case you didn't already know it, the command:

```
heroku db:push
```

will duplicate both the schema AND data of your MySQL development database in heroku's Postgres database. So sticking with MySQL for dev is no problem.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I figured out that ignore my database.yml and I tried to configure DATABASE_URL with this: config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql2://user:password@host/dbname  but don't work, app is looking for db on Amazon server. This is from log: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:37:in `connect': Access denied for user 'etok'@'ec2-174-129-89-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is very straight forward and simple:

1 - create mysql db
2 - create mysql db user (set defaults)
3.1 - Go to your Heroku panel/Config Vars

[image]

3.2 - Click on "Reveal Vars" and edit (clicking on pencil icon) on the one you want to change in this case `DATABASE_URL` (if not present just a new one with `DATABASE_URL` as the name)

[image]

3 (#2) - Using command line

`heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@databasehostIP:databaseserverport/databasename`

then just

`heroku restart`

And remember the syntax:

`DATABASE_URL`

`mysql://user:password@hostnameOrIPAddress:PortNumber/databasename`

MySQL DBMS's default port number is : `3306`

That's why you see examples mentioned previously using `DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@databasehostIP:3306/databasename`

Hope this helps!!!