# Can I connect heroku to an external MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

Can I access an external MySQL database externally from heorku? I've already given access from heroku's IP Address..I got the server's IP from

Yets I'm getting this error:

MySQL Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is another topic related to your question - you might find an answer there:

[Remote mysql database on Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397028/remote-mysql-database-on-heroku-app)