# Application Error on heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I tried to push my first rails project to heroku. But I get "Application Error":
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I can't understand what is the error. My log:

```
C:\Sites\calend>heroku logs
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `require'

←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2013-04-02T16:43:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 crashed
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to
starting
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command
`bundle exec rails server -p 53576`
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:13+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rai
ls 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be remove
d in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in t
o your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the releas
e notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-r
c2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.r
b:5)
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:13+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rai
ls 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be remove
d in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in t
o your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the releas
e notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-r
c2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.r
b:5)
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:13+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rai
ls 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be remove
d in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in t
o your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the releas
e notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-r
c2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.r
b:5)
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 3.2.1 application starti
ng in production on http://0.0.0.0:53576
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_depe
ndency'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connec
tion_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gem
s/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem
': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-a
dapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Call with -d to detach
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connec
tion_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instanc
e_eval'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connec
tion_specification.rb:48:in `resolve_hash_connection'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.
1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connect
ion_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute
_hook'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels)
in <class:Railtie>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_depe
ndency'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adap
ter.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:258:in `setup'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/initializers/de
vise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/initializers/de
vise.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_loa
d_hooks'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:716:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block i
n run_load_hooks'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:En
gine>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in
load'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_depe
ndency'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_depe
ndency'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `require'

←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2013-04-02T16:54:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 crashed
←[33m2013-04-02T16:58:52+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Starting process with command `b
undle exec rake -T` by aigool@mail.ru
←[32m2013-04-02T16:58:54+00:00 heroku[run.1117]:←[0m Awaiting client
←[32m2013-04-02T16:58:54+00:00 heroku[run.1117]:←[0m Starting process with comma
nd `bundle exec rake -T`
←[32m2013-04-02T16:58:56+00:00 heroku[run.1117]:←[0m State changed from starting
 to up
←[32m2013-04-02T16:59:00+00:00 heroku[run.1117]:←[0m Process exited with status
0
←[32m2013-04-02T16:59:00+00:00 heroku[run.1117]:←[0m State changed from up to co
mplete
```

Comment: There are probably other issues going on... but this might be one of your problems: `Please install the postgresql adapter: gem install activerecord-postgresql-a
dapter (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)`

Comment: But I don't use Postgre in my project. I use MySQL.

Comment: Do you use a remote MySQL database? Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397028/remote-mysql-database-on-heroku-app

Comment: can you post your production group from Gemfile ?

Comment: My Gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'calendar_date_select'
gem 'watu_table_builder', :require => "table_builder"
gem 'ice_cube'
gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed in database.yml 'mysql2' to 'postgresql' and added to gemfile "gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'". And now it works. So I can't use mysql database at heroku?

Comment: No heroku supports postgresql, Add gem 'pg' to the Gemfile and push the contents to the heroku hosted branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see it in the error message:

```
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` 
(pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Comment: And please post your database.yml

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed in database.yml 'mysql2' to 'postgresql' and added to gemfile "gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'". And now it works. So I can't use mysql database at heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It is also better to have groups like the following.

Sample Gemfile:

Development Group: sqlite3 because it does not require any any database setup process compared to postgresql

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Production Group

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```