# Login doesn't work with heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Ok this is getting very frustrating, one problem after the next.  I pushed my app to heroku and when I visit the url I get my login screen (as I should).  But when I actually try to login it gives me the "Invalid Username/Password" warning message.  However everything works fine on my localhost.  I'm assuming there is a problem with the app communicating with my database.  I've ran "heroku run rake db:migrate" and no luck.

On my localhost I'm using the standard sqlite3 database but I had to include the gem 'pg' in my gem file when pushing it to heroku to avoid errors.  When I left it as gem sqlite3 i received an error saying it couldn't find sqlite3.h file or something of that nature.

I can see that my database is living on postgres.heroku.com.  I've also installed this gem via the recommendation of heroku support

gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'

Here are some logs from heroku when I try to enter the login info.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
←[36m2013-04-04T14:31:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started POST "/session" for 74.143.68.203 at 2013-04-04 14:31:15 +0000
←[36m2013-04-04T14:31:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
←[36m2013-04-04T14:31:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "authenticity_token"=>"rQ1i9DRCV3qju2+RSBwp/9XYW8+6RiLfKfGZFNEcbT8=", "email"=>"admin@ciagent.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
←[36m2013-04-04T14:31:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
←[36m2013-04-04T14:31:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
←[33m2013-04-04T14:31:16+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=boiling-reef-2060.herokuapp.com fwd="74.143.68.203" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
←[33m2013-04-04T14:31:15+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=POST path=/session host=boiling-reef-2060.herokuapp.com fwd="74.143.68.203" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=1721
```

I just don't understand why I can login when my app is on localhost with the same username/pw but when the app is on heroku it can't recognize the login info.

ADDITIONAL EDIT ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

I opened up the console for my local app and found what I expected when looking for a user:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> user=User.find(1)
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (5.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, email: "admin@ciagent.com", hashed_password: "dc009272b087019fb2b20b691dc827dca1424a1a", created_at: "2010-10-29 19:43:00", updated_at: "2011-01-12 20:07:09", admin: "yes", logo: nil>
```

When I looked for this when I opened the console on heroku here is the error I received.  I'll keep searching for the fix but maybe you guys will see an obvious red flag.

```
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> user=User.find(1)
user=User.find(1)
User Load (39.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with id=1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:343:in `find_one'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:314:in `find_with_ids'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find' from (irb):1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Normally your `development` and `production` environments will refer to different databases, so the same login won't necessarily work on both. Is that what's happening here?

Comment: I don't have a production database in my local db folder.  I've maintained an old heroku app before by pushing and pulling strictly to a development db on my computer.  When I would add records locally and push them the changes would take affect on the heroku hosted app.  I never specified a different username/pw to be used.

Comment: Check what's on your heroku database running console on remote with 
`heroku run rails console` and find items in your users model

Comment: Also, you can use your local database with heroku app and check if login works that way [Remote database on heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397028/remote-mysql-database-on-heroku-app)

Answer (score 3):

When you run the app on your local computer (a.k.a. development) it is using a local `sqlite`  database. When you run it on heroku (a.k.a. production), it uses a cloud-based `postgres` database. This is necessary so that you can make changes and develop the app on your local computer, without having to worry about breaking the live production database. Database settings are in `config/database.yml`.

If you've added the username / password to `db/seeds` or via a migration, you can reasonably expect the same logins to work in development and production. Presumably, this is what you did before, when you say this worked. Either that, or you had both production and development pointing to the same database (NOT recommended).

Because it's not working here, I'm guessing you added the logins via the console, or via the site itself. You can either run `heroku run rails console` to open a console on the production server, and add the logins. Or you can add them via a migration, then run the same migration in production so that they're added there as well.

Comment: I added some additional edits to my initial post, if you could take a look that'd be great.  thanks

Comment: Heroku is telling you there's no `User` with `id` of 1. If you do `User.all` you'll see a list of all users there are. I suspect the list will be empty. Try running `User.create(:email => "admin@ciagent.com", :hashed_password => "dc009272b087019fb2b20b691dc827dca1424a1a", :admin => "yes")`. This should create the same user in production (check with `User.all`) and you should be able to log in.