# Rails ignoring database.yml details about my Heroku PostgreSQL DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I have an Rails app on Heroku and, for some reason, it cannot connect to my production database when I deploy it. Seems to be ignoring anything I enter on database.yml.

This database is not an add-on on this specific Heroku app, but on a different one. However, the database connection details below are correct.

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: unicode
   database: asdfasdfasdf # [HIDDEN]
   pool: 5
   host: ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
   username:  asdfasdfasdf # [HIDDEN]
   port:       5432
   password:  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf # [HIDDEN]
   timeout: 5000
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397028/remote-mysql-database-on-heroku-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku ignore the `database.yml` file properties. You need to set `DATABASE_URL` as environmental value.

```
ENV["DATABASE_URL"]= postgres:username:password@host/db_name
```

**See also:** [Heroku postgresql configuration.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Set DATABASE_URL with below command

```
heroku  config:addDATABASE_URL='postgres://asdfasdfasdf:asdfasdfasdf@ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/asdfasdfasdf'
```