# Using remote MySQL database on Heroku running Django app

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku

I've been struggling with the following problem:
I have a MySQL database running on a remote web host. I connect to the MySQL database in my Django app (I use it as the main database). The Django app is running on a Heroku server but I get different data results  compared to running it locally.

Am I missing something, or are changes done on Heroku not committed to the database?

MySQL settings:

```
DATABASES = {
 #   'default': {
  #      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
   #     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
   # }
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'xxx',
        'PORT': 'xxx',
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your settings. Are you sure the app on Heroku is connecting to the remote MySQL db?

Comment: Updated the question with the MySQL settings. Yes I am sure, though the MySQL database is configured in the Django app, not in Heroku (if possible/necessary).

Comment: And there's nothing else in that settings file that could be overriding that DATABASES setting?

Comment: No, it is the only DATABASES setting in the file. Is it required to host your database on Heroku or should this work (if set up correctly)?

Comment: Assuming your MySQL db is set up to accept connections from the internet, this should work. But if it didn't, your site wouldn't work at all; you wouldn't just get different data. Which is why the only explanation I can think of is that you are somehow overriding your settings somehow. Sorry to keep insisting, but for example are you sure there's no call to `dj_database_url`?

Comment: I scanned the entire file. No possibility of overriding the database setting. Although, as this approach should work the error may be in my remaining code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I just see that if you delete the ad-on provided by heroku, it will use the DB you put on the settings of your project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe Juan Carlos Hernández is correct.  To expand on his answer, Heroku uses it's own database instance, unless you tell it otherwise by pointing the DATABASE_URL to the one you would like to use.  Please note that Heroku will prevent you from overwriting the DATABASE_URL in use since that will destroy the existing database.  Although tagged as ruby-on-rails, the answers I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397028/remote-mysql-database-on-heroku-app/49713411#49713411) seem relevant.

To summarize, you just have to run

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@databasehostIP:3306/databasename
heroku config:add SHARED_DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@databasehostIP:3306/databasename
```

Then do

```
heroku restart
```

Or you can change these variables in the Heroku panel.