# Connect Heroku deployed MySQL database to Django

Tags: mysql, django, database, heroku

I want to make connection with my MySQL database which is deployed on Heroku. However, after setting parameters for database I am getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user '*mu username*'@'%' to database '*name of my database*'")
```

In my settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {  
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '*name of my database*',
    'USER': '*my username*',
    'PASSWORD': '*my password*',
    'HOST': 'eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com',
    'PORT': '3306',
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big expert but in my case, an automatic PostgreSQL database is attached to the project when started. Also, DATABASE_URL is set as protected variable in your app and points to the PostgreSQL DB.

You can try to delete the add-on so the variable disappears and then create a new one: `DATABASE_URL -> mysql://username:<password>@hostname:port/databasename`

You can get some more info about and almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544766/using-remote-mysql-database-on-heroku-running-django-app).